# Best practices for restricting developer access to UAT and production environments, yet still getting anything done

Tags: java, security, testing, project-management

I am working with a small company, that is going through the growing pains of transitioning from a start-up culture to a more mature corporate culture.  In the past, developers have had more or less free reign to access UAT environments, and even wide latitude to access production.

However, under the new approach, developers have access only to the Dev and initial QA environments... and are locked out of UAT and production.  All access to those environments, from deploying code (Java WAR's in this case), to managing Java app servers, to even reviewing logs and the database, has to funnel through a sysadmin.

It's still early on, but so far this approach does not appear tenable.  The net result is that every time there is a production issue, ***or even just a bug ticket entered in UAT***... it requires an "all hands" meeting, with half the department crammed into someone's office or huddled around one person's monitor.

I would like to propose something more workable, while still satisfying the need to restrict access to sensitive user data, etc.  One idea that comes to mind is to create a readonly-mount for the log file directory, at some other location where developers may at least view the application-level logs.  However, beyond that I am interested in best practices for how to restrict developer access while taking the smallest productivity hit possible.

NOTE:  I did find some vaguely-similar questions before I wrote this one.  However, they were either [too narrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285731/best-practice-for-test-and-production-environments) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76210/production-test-developer-environments-vs-security)), or [dealt with Sarbanes-Oxley matters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548738/does-sox-restrict-access-to-qa-environments-or-just-production) not at issue here, or [simply asked "are these restrictions normal?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142028/what-should-developers-have-access-to) rather than asking how to cope with them.

Comment: better would be ask this question http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions full list of sites http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: this is exactly on topic at security.stackexchange.com as it comes under governance and risk management - I would suggest migrating it there. And read http://security.stackexchange.com/q/6626/485

Comment: Thanks, guys.  However, StackExchange is becoming so senselessly overgrown and fragmented, there are probably a dozen sub-sites on which this question *could* plausibly fit.  The fact that two different ones were suggested within 100 seconds of each other just shows how overlapping they all are.  Nevertheless, StackOverflow remains one of those appropriate sites, as suggested by the lengthy "Related" list on the right.

Comment: I don't really mind there being a slew of sister sites, even if there is a ton of overlap between them.  It's just a bummer that when you ask anything more subjective than "please diagnose this error message"... these days it turns into a "Wikipedia-lawyer" thing half the time.

Comment: @Steve Perkins: good luck when moving to a *"more mature"* environments.  I've worked both for startups and for a > $130 bn company.  The > $130 bn was wwaayyy more immature with their silly restrictions.  The different environments were so pathetically setup that the lost of productivity was sky-rocketing.  Forcing developers to open tickets after tickets to try to understand bugs that would only happen in prod.  End result?  Developers ended up knowing the main production DB passwords (I know, I know).  +1 to your question that said: it is a **very** good question.

Comment: @Steve Perkins: basically what I see as the worst issue was that the Un*x admins and DBAs were clueless about Java and so they couldn't really help the Java devs diagnosing the issues.  First consequence: some stupid Java devs thought that by logging **everything** (every single setter and getter etc.) it would help.  Now you had new problems: uber-gigantic log files (sometimes on preprod systems without disk quota).  Pure madness.  So think about it: if you have to parse hundreds of Gb of logs and require the help of Un*x/DBAs admins to diagnose Java issues, you're SOL.

Comment: @Steve Perkins: the read-only log you mention is what we had (read-only logs for production systems) but it's far from enough.  I won't even start about the silly *"Un*x and DBAs had to replace prod passwords with *** so that the devs wouldn't see the real passwords"* requirements.  It's delusional.  One time out of three the admins would forget to replace/hide the real username/passwords and anyway once in a while we'd have user escalating the support chain to end up speaking to an actual dev and they'd gladly give us their passwords.  And that's how we'd get job done in a timely manner.  :((

Comment: @Steve Perkins: regarding the Wikipedia-lawyer thing I feel for you too.  SO sadly has a lot of shortcomings.  One day someone will come with a mix between SO and the good old Usenet hierarchy and we'll have a winner.  Until then we're stuck with SO :(

Comment: @StevePerkins This is such an important question to ask. Any developer working in a small company that grows will at some point deal with this. Thanks for asking the question.

Answer (score 5):

We made that change in the last few years here. We however allow most developers access to production logs and read access to the database. We simply don't allow them to change anything directly on production. All changes must be code reviewed and code is pushed first to QA for testing and then to prod by either configuration management or the technical leads.

We also frequently refresh our dev environments with prod data. Since all dev changes to the databse and to database data like lookup tables are scripted and storeded in source control, it is not hard to refresh from prod and then quickly load all the dev changes. Since a good number of the reported issues have to do with the data that is in prod for one or more particular records, this helps us to see a more accurate view of the prod data. Having a separate dev server for project development and one for support of existing prod issues could work too. That way you don't mess up the people working on project work by refreshing the data base to work on a bug reported from prod. Hardware is cheap compared to the cost of a bunch of people sitting in one room looking at one screen to try to fix a problem. It probably take avoiding only two or three of those meetings to justify the cost of a server that can be easily refreshed with prod data.

Our users are aslo well-trained to provide screen shots. Amazing how many things can be fixed by seeing the screen shot. Sometimes the fix is easy (the user is looking at the wrong screen) and sometimes you can see that the record has data you didn't think it could have or lacks data it should have. (Who changed that field from not nullable to nullable? No wonder the code is broken.)

We also use our audit tables extensively to find where the problem might be. We store what application made the data changes as well as the change since we have many possible applications hitting the same database. It is helpful being able to see exactly who or what changed the dat to it's current incorrect state. That helps us find where to start to fix the problem very quickly.

If the data is restricted (we have developers in another country who cannot see prod at all), the it is up to the tech lead to do the research to find what is causing the problem and then assign the fix to a developer after providing him with details from his research. This makes one person responsible for the research, not the whole team and devs don't get involved until after the intial research is done.

It wasn't an easy change culturally. People rsisted at first and hated losing their prod rights. But after awhile people came to grateful that they didn't have to make changes directly on prod (and get whacked if something went wrong! Oops forgot to highlight the where clause and deleted the whole user table.) We were grateful that we had the chance for code review and QA testing (which we also didn't have when devs had prod rights). We saw first hand that there were fewer crisies created by a bad push to prod under pressure or by doing something directly on prod and forgetting to do it to dev to (or put in source control), so those times a later push from dev overwrote a change on prod went away. And we were oh so glad that no one was deleting the whole user table by accident (thank god for audit tables) anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Well, here are some thoughts

- Have the log files exposed as read only. Make them available on
  request, or serve them up via HTTP to a page so developers can get at
  them when they need them. If you make sure you don't log customer
  information to the logs, that makes it easier to get this agreed
  upon.
- Personally I don't think it is a bad thing to allow developers read
  only access to the application server console screens (for example a
  WebSphere Application Server). This way, you can view settings.
  Passwords and things should be hidden anyway, so it isn't like you
  can steal secrets. Plus, by view only, you can see if something is
  amiss, and always request higher up sysadmins to make the changes
  needed.
- If your company has the time to do it, it would be worth classifying
  your data. What is customer-based? What is data that may be the
  "secret" to how your company does business versus other competitors.
  If you classify your data, you can now better define who can have
  what access to what. Even in production, the DBA's could set up some
  developer user ids that allow you select (read) access on the
  classifications of data that are ok to look at. Anything that needs a
  clearance, you may have to go to the DBA for, but...you can at least
  query for some things without needing the whole "war room" to do so.
- If you afford to build and maintain it, have a mirror of production
  somewhere. This mirror is configured exactly the same as production.
  It has the most recently deployed version of the application there.
  And if you need production data, you take a back up of the data from
  production, run it through a "scrubber" or "scrambler" if you need to
  so satisfy your execs, and the upload it to this mirror. Voila! You
  now have as close to production as possible, but you are allowed to
  have more authority in this environment to troubleshoot. This will
  give you everything except exact production data (since it was
  scrambled). If the bug turns out to be something along the lines of
  specific data, then you go back to querying production and/or working
  with the DBA on it.
- Also, perhaps it would be worthwhile to have some profiles on
  standby? Perhaps your sysadmins could grant you some temporary
  authorities to things? This could be argued as good or bad either way
  and is ultimately a company policy.
- Also having a good change management system in place goes a long way
  to identifying candidates for what just went wrong. If your
  application suddenly crashes, it would be helpful to know that the
  sysadmins just applied an OS patch to production and this OS patch
  may in fact be affecting your application. Or maybe somebody else
  moved a fix to production and didn't fully test it. But you at least
  know what could be potential candidates for breaking things.

Ultimately, all of these things or others, are things that your company and your IS/IT department need to decide. Perhaps this is something to discuss with your CIO? Or your manager? (Of course it depends on how well they accept feedback and comments. Where I work, I'm very lucky that they appreciate those kinds of thoughts from us.) Perhaps, now is the time to begin to discuss these things.

Also it doesn't hurt to present the cost of the risks versus the benefits. If a temporary grant of authority to the logs, the db, etc. gets you "up" in production, perhaps that risk, is outweighed by the satisfaction felt by your customers, both internal and external.

Anyway, just some thoughts to think about. I'm not sure if there is a right or wrong here. It is just something every company has to make their own and then live with their choices. But kudos to you for getting the ball rolling on this conversation.